# Mutable nearsest neighbors?

Tags: database, machine-learning, data-structures, reinforcement-learning, nearest-neighbor

I'm trying to find a nearrest neighbor for a given data point, then add the data point without rebuilding the entire NN database as that would be too costly. Are there any methods that are efficient in which I can add the data point without rebuilding. Are there any optimization workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Many spatial indexes allow kNN search and modification (add/remove/relocate): kd-tree, R-Tree, quadtree, LSH, ... .
Some spatial indexes allow modifications in principle, but modifications probably are prohibitivley slow, e.g. CoverTree.

All of the above give precise answers to NN queries.

I don't know how well approximate NN (ANN) indexes can be updated.